# Rails 4 nested forms and strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, strong-parameters

I cannot get accepts_nested_attributes_for to work with strong parameters in Rails 4. This is the error

```
Processing by CityaddressesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cx9nunLAsHkvo/Z8vKnWFnrub1LpmUgVNdePcQ9VDSQ=", "cityaddress"=>{"st_unit"=>"1", "st_num"=>"1", "st_prefix"=>"E", "name"=>"1", "st_type"=>"ST", "st_postalcode"=>"", "description"=>"", "cityaccount"=>{"name"=>"1", "description"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Create Cityaddress"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1[0m
Unpermitted parameters: cityaccount
```

This is the model:

```
class Cityaddress < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cityaccounts
    has_many :license_plates
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cityaccounts, allow_destroy: true

    def street_address
      return "#{st_unit} #{st_num} #{name} #{st_type} #{st_prefix}"
    end
    def address
      return "#{st_unit}#{st_prefix} #{name} #{st_type} #{st_num} "
    end
end
```

This is the controller:

```
  # GET /cityaddresses/new
  def new
    @cityaddress = Cityaddress.new
    @streets = Street.where("active=1").order("display_order")
    @cityaddress_accounts = @cityaddress.cityaccounts.build
  end

    def cityaddress_params
      params.require(:cityaddress).permit(:st_unit, :st_num, :st_prefix, :name, :st_type, :st_postalcode, :description, cityaccounts_attributes: [:name, :description, :id])
    end
```

This is the view:

```
<%= f.fields_for @cityaddress_accounts do |ff| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= ff.label :name %>
     <%= ff.text_field :name %><br>
   </div> 
   <div class="field">
     <%= ff.label :description %>
     <%= ff.text_field :description %><br>
   </div>  
<% end %>
```

I'm thinking it's something to do with the strong parameter syntax?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to change the view a bit.

Try changing this

```
<%= f.fields_for @cityaddress_accounts do |ff| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :cityaccounts do |ff| %>
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I'm wondering why, though. I didn't create a :cityaccounts variable...

Comment: It is the association name that you need to define as it is a nested attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems all correct, but try in Controller do this:

```
  def new
    @cityaddress = Cityaddress.new
    @streets = Street.where("active=1").order("display_order")
    @cityaddress.cityaccounts.build
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. That didn't break anything and the @cityaddress_accounts variable was superfluous, I guess...